# File after using php's unlink function

Tags: php

What happens when you unlink a file say for instance a video file from your server with PHP's `unlink()` function apart from deletion?
Will the file be deleted permanently?

Comment: It does whatever your underlying OS's delete mechanisms dictate. Since you've provided no details whatsoever about your server, we can't answer ANYTHING.

Comment: It does just what it says it does, it `unlink`s the file on the disk. It does not go to a trash bin or anything like that, or try to securely erase it.

Comment: @MarcB say server is Apache. Does it make any difference if I use IIS?

Comment: apache has **NOTHING** to do with deleting files. That's like saying "My bedroom is painted blue. will it be waterproof?"

Comment: @MarcB what details you want from the server mate? How does server differentiation would change the unlink function?

Comment: On Windows it does a delete like doing `del` in a command prompt so it won't go to  recycle bin.

Comment: windows? osx? linux? solaris? VMS? Eniac? what kind of file system? local attached disk? SAN? NAS? blah blah blah.

Comment: @AmirHassanAzimi: The word "server" is overloaded in this context.  A physical (or virtual) host is a "server" which runs an OS.  Within that running OS could be any number of application-level instances which are "servers" in that they provide a service of some kind (usually over a network interface).  I suspect you're referring to the latter usage while Marc is referring to the former.

Comment: thanks @David i think i have my answer now. Other mates are acting some how like I am asking them to lend me some money or something. As far as I know Operating system is different than servers. Well servers run in OS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will the file be deleted permanently or is it still somewhere in the server?

The file will be deleted.  If the server's OS and/or file system has a mechanism to recover deleted files, then it may be recoverable by that mechanism.  If the file system doesn't over-write the location of the file on the storage medium (which is very likely) then the physical data is still on the disk and could potentially be recovered prior to that space being reclaimed by another file.

> Will the file be removed securely or PHP just like other operating systems unlinks the file from your HDD?

The file will be deleted.  However your OS and/or file system handles deletes, that mechanism will be invoked.

> Where does the file go after using this function.

The file will be deleted.  If deleting a file in your OS and/or file system results in *moving* that file somewhere, it may end up in that location.  If not, it won't.

---

In short... It deletes the file.  It doesn't copy the file, move the file, replace the file, etc.  It deletes the file.  In *most* file systems this means removing the entry in the file system's index corresponding to that file.  The location on the disk which stores the actual data of the file is unchanged, but the file system now interprets that location as "free space" and may write to it at any time.