# After unlink a file/image where it goes?

Tags: php

I am going to use the php unlink function as,

```
$file = 'dir/test.php';
unlink($file );
```

It deletes the file successfully.Now my question is that where i found this file after deletion,means in Recycle Bin or somewhere else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File after using php's unlink function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374378/file-after-using-phps-unlink-function)

Answer (score 3):

Please read this

Will the file be deleted permanently or is it still somewhere in the server?

> The file will be deleted. If the server's OS and/or file system has a
>   mechanism to recover deleted files, then it may be recoverable by that
>   mechanism. If the file system doesn't over-write the location of the
>   file on the storage medium (which is very likely) then the physical
>   data is still on the disk and could potentially be recovered prior to
>   that space being reclaimed by another file.

Will the file be removed securely or PHP just like other operating systems unlinks the file from your HDD?

> The file will be deleted. However your OS and/or file system handles
>   deletes, that mechanism will be invoked.

Where does the file go after using this function?

> The file will be deleted. If deleting a file in your OS and/or file
>   system results in moving that file somewhere, it may end up in that
>   location. If not, it won't.

**From:**
[File after using php's unlink function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374378/file-after-using-phps-unlink-function)